# PHP Inserting into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm almost certain that I'm missing something extremely stooopid here but the longer I look at it the angrier I get.

When I execute follow.php, nothing gets inserted into the database, and there's no errors either.
Before anyone says it. Yes I know there's SQL injection holes here. It's unfinished code!

config.php:

```
session_start();
$mysql_hostname = "XXXX";
$mysql_user = "XXXX";
$mysql_password = "XXXX";
$mysql_database = "XXXX";
$bd = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) 
or die("Opps something went wrong");
mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $bd) or die("Opps something went wrong");
```

follow.php:

```
session_start();
include('config.php');
$user_check=$_SESSION['login_user'];

$tagID=$_POST['id'];
$recID="select UserID from useradmin where username='$user_check' ";

$updatesql="INSERT INTO following (RecID, followID) VALUES ($recID, $tagID)";

mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $bd) or die("Opps some thing went wrong");

mysql_query($updatesql, $bd)
```

A bit more information. The output of my insert statement is:

```
INSERT INTO following (RecID, followID) VALUES (, 100006)
```

So the $recid isn't being populated...

Comment: 1. have you tried echoing your select statement to see if it is returning anything?  2. what is $rec?  You do not have it mentioned anywhere, is it supposed to be $recID?  Also, if you are calling your database in config, you don't need to do it again in follow.php

Comment: what var_dump(mysql_query($updatesql, $bd)) says ??

Comment: @Jim sorry $rec should be $recID...

Comment: Since you're learning, STOP IMMEDIATELY, forget everything about mysql_* functions and take a look about the PDO library. You'll be grateful you did. The manual is here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: Add LIMIT 1 to first query:
$recID="select UserID from useradmin where username='$user_check' LIMIT 1";
It is not necessary but recommended :)

Comment: Thanks, I will be sure to look at this. At this point though I'm just trying to build a proof of concept. I'll be sure to go through this for the final version though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the last line of your code to

```
    mysql_query($updatesql, $bd) or die(mysql_error());
```

**EDIT**

You should change this

```
   $recID="select UserID from useradmin where username='$user_check' ";
```

to

```
  $sql_rec = "select UserID from useradmin where username='$user_check' ";
  $rs_rec = mysql_query($sql_rec);
  $data_rec = mysql_fetch_object($rs_rec);

  $recID = $data_rec->UserID;
```

The $recID will now have a value and the INSERT will work

Comment: Just amended that. I now get: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' 100006)' 100006 is 'id'. Seems to be putting a space before the id?

Comment: This did it. Thank you so much. I've developed multiple grey hairs over the last 30 minutes...

Answer (score 2):

I can see you defining $recID, but using $rec.

Is there any chance, you would like to run the $recID query and save the returned value into $rec, before running $updatesql?

Comment: no sorry this was my mistake. $rec should be $recid. Question updated.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$updatesql="INSERT INTO following (RecID, followID) VALUES ('".$rec"', '".$tagID."')";
```

Comment: RecID, followID are integers no escape is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create your query using mysqli

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("select UserID from useradmin where username=?");
$stmt->bind_param('s',$user_check);

$stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->get_result();

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO following (RecID, followID) VALUES (?,?))";
$stmt->bind_param('si',$rec, $tagID);
$stmt->execute();
```

See tutorial here http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: Thanks, although I get syntax error, unexpected ';' on line 23. 23 being This: $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO following (RecID, followID) VALUES (?,?))";

Comment: the line $stmt->bind_param('si',$rec,$tagID); treats the $rec as a string and $tagID as int, maybe $tagID is a string?